# Sass Nesting for :hover does not work

Tags: sass, css-selectors

I've written this code, but it does not work. What is my problem?

```
.class {
    margin:20px;
    :hover {
        color:yellow;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1113, accepted):

For concatenating selectors together when nesting, you need to use the parent selector (`&`):

```
.class {
    margin:20px;
    &:hover {
        color:yellow;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me, __was missing__ the "**&**" symbol!

Answer (score 67):

You can easily debug such things when you go through the generated CSS. In this case the pseudo-selector after conversion has to be attached to the class. Which is not the case. Use "&".

http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector

```
.class {
    margin:20px;
    &:hover {
        color:yellow;
    }
}
```